# Problem using selenium's web driver to fetch coronavirus data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a Python script to fetch coronavirus data from [Wordlometers](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/') using selenium's webdriver. My script consists of this:

```
class Coronavirus():
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
        chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)

    def get_data(self):
        try:
            self.driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
            table = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_table_countries"]/tbody[1]')
            country_element = table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Italy')]")
            row = country_element.find_element_by_xpath("./..")
```

but what happens is that Chrome opens and closes immediately. I tried debugging this script adding some prints here and there, and it turns out that the line `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath` doesn't let me print anything else after. I tried reading the documentation but I can't get it to print anything, what can I do to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest to remove the try/exception logic and post the error that appears in your terminal. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have lots of code in the `try` block, which generally isn't good.  One of those statements is throwing an error, which causes the rest of the code in the block to be skipped.

Comment: Your xpath isn't found on the page, `//*[@id="main_table_countries"]/tbody[1]`, I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll get to work now :)

Comment: @MentallyRecursive I think that's what doesn't work. I tried in so many different ways but I can't find alternatives. How would you grab the country table?

Comment: An XPath to get the row for a certain country, I would use something like this: `//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//tr[descendant-or-self::*[text()='Italy']]`

Comment: @MentallyRecursive you are a genius, thank you!